# Dark theme got high contrast colors

Tags: discussion, design, dark-mode

I noticed today that the color scheme was changed on Stack Overflow website, at least for Dark theme.

The new color scheme is much more **high contrast** (relatively) than it was before. I even went to my profile to see if there was any changes in the settings. I found a *high contrast* setting, but it was *disabled*. I enabled it, and it was another color scheme, also *high contrast*.

Is there a way change the dark theme less **high contrast**, especially as there already is an option to turn on **high contrast**, if that is wanted.

Perhaps there can be another setting, **less contrast dark theme**?

---

Two changes stands out to me:

- darker background (makes higher contrast to text)
- higher contrast on the tags

---

This is how the **new** Dark Theme with **higher contrasts** looks:
[image: dark theme]

Here is how the **previous** Dark Theme with **more "calm" contrasts** looks:
[image]

And here is the *real* high contrast colors:
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched

Comment: "*Perhaps there can be another setting, less contrast dark theme?*" it's what the high contrast mode is turning into.

Comment: And here was me thinking that the high contrast mode that I've used since release has all of a sudden become low contrast mode

Comment: the colors are a lot more muted too. old dark mode was just right for me

Comment: The light theme also has noticeably more contrast.

Comment: This new theme hurts my eyes. A *less contrast* mode that's just the old theme would be great.

Comment: All the tags in light theme are now black. This is very weird.

Comment: I really don't understand the decision behind changing it to pure black (#000000) background with white text. It's one of the worst combinations in terms of accessibility for most people.

Comment: Pity I can't use it, because browser has forced colors because setting a high contrast on every website is unfeasible. Need HTTP protocol development to have a ghost of a chance of fixing.