Updated tag design is too heavy on font and attention grabbing and may be confused with code formatting
I noticed (just a few minutes ago) that now the tags are shown in bold, like c++. Before this, the tags were shown in the normal way/fonts (not bold). This seems to have happened site-wide.
In particular, I find the change uneasy and too attention-grabbing to the eyes. Maybe they just look odd to me. I think that the old way of showing tags was fine and this should be reverted.
So I am asking if others also feel the same.

Cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/400086/1416577

I'm guessing it's another accessibility "feature".

To boldly go where no designer has been before.

Relevant comment here. Reproduced to make it easy to read: "A new tag style has been released which has improved this contrast. More details here"

Tag rendering has had many problems with the new coloring, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426889/dark-theme-got-high-contrast-colors

I read this post and I thought the [c++] was a codeblock instead of tag formatting. Does this look the same for anyone else too?

Yep. That's the new tag formatting. Required meta tags were done dirty here too - the only difference between normal and required tags is an outline now

No thanks to the bold font in tags. Revert pls.

The redesign might've been a bold decision, but the font kinda weight on me, with tags popping out and i strongly disagree with how it looks and suggest reverting it back to how it was.

@dan1st yes, I did. I am extremely disappointed with SE's choice of design for this. I feel it'd encourage even more people to use unnecessary code blocks in their posts when. This already happens often enough when people decide to code format the names of programming languages. Now SE is setting the example for them to do so.

Likely because I have crap eyesight and totally ed colour vision, I like the new style.

@user4581301 I wish I had your kind of crappy eyesight, because my crappy eyesight cannot stand this change.

I'm not too fond of it either.  And are these changes ever announced anywhere?  I had to ask a question on meta to get to this answer (I used the wrong keywords in search).   The powers that be keep doing this stuff making me think I accidentally changed something on my browser.  This happened before with the increased line spacing.  I wish they would stop doing this!!.

If this is done for accessibility, it should be optional.

Tags, as they appear in question/answer/comment text should be made bold to distinguish them from code blocks. However, the tags listed below the questions should not be made bold, as they stand out way to much. As @Exa mentioned, if this was done for accessibility, then please give us an option to unbold them (and/or make them not bold by default and so those who need to can set the option to bold face them).

There are quite a few things that could stand fixing or improving upon.  This was not one of them.

Please let's not bike-shed this discussion to death.

@Flimm: Stack Exchange doesn't listen to reason, they listen to volume.

My first impression ... Was ... GLARING NEON

with dark mode on, tags are now like dazzling headlights

@GrafiCode Dark mode is a mess here anyway, imo.

@Lundin Dammit Jim! I'm a doctor; not a UX dev.

I'll cite Jon Skeet who once said Please could you stop using so much bold?

I've never had any problems with SO's various design changes over the years except this one. I can't get over it for some reason. I'm trying though, I really am.

Having now arrived home I too find this change unsettling; with my home PC, the combination of font and bold selected is unsuitable for general use. With my work PC's font choices, it was a questionable design choice; with my home PC's font choices, it's a straight up bad one.
I immediately got a usable font on changing the font generating style to serif. Sans serif ought to work here but didn't. I can't quite figure out why. Blanking the font selector altogether results in a usable sans serif font.
This was done by opening F12 developer tools, finding a tag, and editing the CSS rules that applied to the tag (thus changing all tags on the page).
I'm still leveling colors due to eye problems; I don't want to revert to the days of leveling fonts too.

To me, the tags now feel really pushy - they take way too much attention off the main content of the post and draw eyes to the tag, which is less important than the actual content.
I find it hard to concentrate on the actual post content, as my attention is constantly diverted. I've actually found it so distracting at points that I end up copying and pasting the post text into a text browser just because it's hard to concentrate on reading the text.
It would be great if this change was optional - if it's an accessibility feature, then it probably should be!

as someone with bad eye sight i find the new tag style hard to read and in some cases even impossible to read

So, accessibility has gotten worse, for you. That's probably exactly what they were trying to improve...

I see no problem with this change, and to be honest before I saw this question I didn't even notice that the change had happened.
I am happy for this to remain or to have an option to switch it off, but I personally see no reason to revert the change.

I agree. It's unbelievable how a small portion of the userbase tries to keep stackoverflow hostage with their complaining about literally anything.

"or to have an option to switch it off" Introducing options to toggle any and all design changes isn't scalable. You're increasing the amount of possible looks exponentially, meaning the testing required increases exponentially.

@BjornDeRijcke A small portion? 141 upvotes at time of writing. That's not just the "Meta regulars". This change drew people to Meta.

...and just as many on meta.stackexchange, people who never even use SO. This affects the whole network, making it a worse place.

I advise not voting to delete this post; while the author may do so and I would take no offense; I will not silence his voice merely for being unpopular.
